4- controlled- Z gate (C4Z gate) formation using C4X and Hadamard gates
I require a quantum circuit that utilizes C4X and Hadamard gates to form a C4X gate. Could anyone please help me?


Hi welcome to QC SE. It seems this is a task you are required to complete, so a better way to pose your question is by explaining what you have tried so far, explain why you think your approach isn't working, and ask specifically what you think you need help with (code implementation, conceptual understanding, etc).
